# wpdb в wp query оптимизация запроса

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
$postids = $wpdb->get_results(" 
SELECT p.ID 
FROM g5t_posts p 
JOIN g5t_postmeta p2 ON p.ID=p2.post_id 
JOIN g5t_postmeta p3 ON p.ID=p3.post_id 
WHERE 
(p2.meta_key = 'sticky' AND 
p2.meta_value = '1' AND 
p3.meta_key = 'sticky_date' AND 
DATE_ADD(p.post_modified, INTERVAL + p3.meta_value DAY) >= NOW()) AND 
p.post_status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY p2.meta_value DESC, p.post_date DESC 
LIMIT $limit_posts 
");//Запрос на вывод закрепленных постов
```

Можно ли как-то оптимизировать запрос? Или конвертировать его в wp_query. Если есть что-то жутко неграмотное, укажите пожалуйста

Comment: А чем не устроило с wp_query.? Зачем этот огород?

Comment: Так вот как собрать его в wp_query?

Comment: _DATE_ADD(p.post_modified, INTERVAL + p3.meta_value DAY) >= NOW())_ - конвертируйте в сравнение p3.meta_value и DATEDIFF остальных параметров, это позволит использовать индекс g5t_postmeta(meta_key, meta_value) более эффективно.

Comment: см https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#kombinirovanie-parametrov

Comment: @Akina Уважаемая Akina, Вы предлагаете оптимизацию запроса или конвертацию его в wp_query ?

Comment: @SeVlad Уважаемый человек, прошу учесть тот факт, что я использую 2 meta_key и meta_value, во всех примерах приведены только 1. 
Плюс к этому в where есть строка `DATE_ADD(p.post_modified, INTERVAL + p3.meta_value DAY) >= NOW())` которую я не могу представить в массиве wp_query.
Плюс к этому всему сортировка идет по 2 полям

Comment: @RomualdShmidtelson Эммм... конечно, оптимизация.